# How can I hide some form fields using session state after form submission?

Tags: asp.net

I wanted to know if it is possible when using ASP.NET session state to be able to hide text fields and button for a period of time after a form has been submitted?

Comment: Do you want to hide it client side, perhaps with jquery? or server side after a postback?  Both of these things are possible, what have you researched/tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a timer control. Just set the Enabled property to false to start with.  Then on your page load event check to make sure IsPostBack is True, and if so, 1) Set all the visible properties of the controls to 'false', 2) Set the Interval to however long you want the controls to be invisible; and 3) enable the timer. Then just make sure you create an Event Handler function for the OnTick event of the timer.  In that routine, you would set all the controls visible properties back to 'true'. and then just make sure to set the timer's enabled property back to false.

I know you asked about using ASP session state, but that is only going to come into play once a postback to the page occurs. So..Yes... you could do something with the Global.asax page to make the inputs visible again once the session times out, but unless the user does some action to post back to the page, you aren't going to be able to determine if the session has timed out. So if you wanted the inputs to only be invisible for 5 mins - they arent magically going to turn visible again after the 5 mins is over unless a postback occurs. If no postback occurs for half an hour, they are going to stay invisible during that whole time, even if you set your session to only be 5 minutes long.

The timer control is an AJAX control that will allow the "clock to start" on the client's side, and regardless of postbacks.

---

If you don't want to use the AJAX extensions you could insert your own javascript into the page. Put an asp hidden field on your form called "hfMakeVisibleTimer", and set its value to "0". IN your code behind for the form (when its postback) make sure to set the value of this hidden field to the session Timeout:

```
hfMakeVisibleTimer.Value = (Session.Timeout * 1000).ToString();
```

Create a javascript function on your page to make the controls visible again:

```
function MakeControlsVisible() {
    document.getElementById("control1").style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("control1").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("control2").style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("control2").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("control3").style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("control3").style.visibility = "visible";     
}
```

Then just add this snippet of javascript to a Body OnLoad event:

```
var myVal = document.getElementById("hfMakeVisibleTimer").value;
if (myVal != "0") {
    window.setTimeout(MakeControlsVisible(),myVal);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, however my project doesn't use the AJAX extensions. I was wondering if there is a built in method to hide a couple form fields after post, for the default session state time period for an anonymous user.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide you an option that does not use the AJAX extensions.